# Prevent inheritance link color secondary menu

Tags: routes, theming

I'm creating a lay-out for my website with Zen in Drupal 7. I want links in the body to be red and bold, so I customized the `normalize.css` file:

```
a:link,a:visited {
  color:#990000;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color:#990000;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

I noticed that the links in the secondary menu were affected by this too. This isn't exactly what I want, so I tried to color them white again by changing the navigation.css file:

```
#secondary-menu {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, because the color of the secondary menu is apparentely inherited (I discoverd this with Firebug).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CSS.

Comment: Hi Jeroen :) I have no intention to be mean, I was just stating my opinion. As far as I can tell, still, the question is simply completely unrelated to both Drupal AND Zen. Each SE site needs to set their limits somewhere, or each site would soon be about everything and question quality would quickly drop. I would find the CSS tag appropriate, if, for example, the question was about how to load a specific CSS under only certain Drupal specific conditions, say, "When looking at a particular View", or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#secondary-menu {
  float: right;
}

#secondary-menu a:link,
#secondary-menu a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This way, the menu will be placed on the right, and the menu items will be in the right order, not reverse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this too yesterday, but I had to cope with a new problem. The links are white, but the spacing between them is gone: they are 'glued' together and their order is reversed. Orgininally it looked like:

**My page   Contact   Log out**

Now it looks like:

**Log outContactMy page**

Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: It's because of you are telling them to float right. If you remove this line, the ordering will be fine again.

Comment: If you want the whole menu to float right, you should tell it in a separate rule. I'll edit my answer according to that.